# Visual Studio 2013 lags after typing class in html file

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

Every time I type class in a html file in Visual Studio the app stops responding for a few seconds, presumably it's building the intellisense list of classes available. How can I disable this?

Strangely this is on a fresh install of VS2013 on a fresh install of win 10. It was not lagging like this when I was running under Win 8.1 even with a number of extensions running.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I discovered that this the auto-completion for CSS classes can be turned off by going to Tools->Options and in the Options dialog going to Text Editor->HTML->General and unchecking 'Auto list members' as shown in the screenshot below.

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much, this problem has been bugging me for months now (so much so that I would sometimes copy & paste CSS classes from notepad into visual studio just to avoid the lag).

Comment: great, happy this helped someone else. it was a huge annoyance